# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tinydb'

Tags: python, python-3.x

from tinydb import TinyDB, Query

I get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tinydb' even though...

I have already downloaded the module, when I run pip3 install tinydb: Requirement already satisfied: tinydb in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (3.15.2)

Comment: are you running your file with python3?

Comment: Are you into a Virtual Environment or installed the package outside or inside a Venv?

Comment: `pythonyouareusing -m pip install tinydb` then `pythonyouareusing your_script.py`

Comment: it works when I run the script with python3 as opposed to just with python. Thanks @modesitt.